# Add JSON Valuetypes to XML Nodes using SQL

Tags: json, sql-server, xml, value-type

I have the below XML output generated using SQL query(added in the rextester link):

```
<Main xmlns:json="http://www.samplenamespace.com/json">
 <ID>1001</ID>
 <details>
    <name>John</name>
    <age>12</age>
 </details>
</Main>
```

I want to know how to add a namespace `xmlns:json="http://www.samplenamespace.com/json"` to the 'Main' node.

desired outcome:

```
<Main xmlns:json="http://www.samplenamespace.com/json">
 <ID json:ValueType="Number">1001</ID>
 <details>
    <name>John</name>
    <age>12</age>
 </details>
</Main>
```

rextester link: http://rextester.com/FAV86925

any help?!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I've got this correctly, but this query would create your XML in one go. If there is no `1:n` relation for `<details>` you don't need the sub-select.

btw: You should not store the age as int but store the DOB and compute the age on demand.

```sql
create table #Cdetails(cid int, name varchar(5), age int)
insert into #Cdetails
values(1001,'John',12),
(1002,'Rick',19),
(1003,'Diane',25),
(1004,'Kippy',26)

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.samplenamespace.com/json' as json)  
select 'Number' AS [ID/@json:ValueType]
      ,cd1.cid AS ID
      ,cd1.[name] AS [details/name]
      ,cd1.age AS [details/age]
from #Cdetails cd1
For XML Path('Main');
```

The result

```
<Main xmlns:json="http://www.samplenamespace.com/json">
  <ID json:ValueType="Number">1001</ID>
  <details>
    <name>John</name>
    <age>12</age>
  </details>
</Main>
<Main xmlns:json="http://www.samplenamespace.com/json">
  <ID json:ValueType="Number">1002</ID>
  <details>
    <name>Rick</name>
    <age>19</age>
  </details>
</Main>
... more of them
```